# Maximum item size in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I'm working on a simple web utility that makes use of IndexedDB (similar to a key-value DB) feature of HTML5.

I was looking for but I was unable to know: what is the maximum size I can store in an item?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific limit for a size of a single item, only a global limit.

The rules regarding the global limit have changed since this answer was originally written. The [up-to-date docs are on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria#Storage_limits) - depending on the available disk space, the "group" limit (for the given domain, including all of its subdomains) **can range from 10 MB to 2 GB.**

---

The older answer - obsoleted with the release of Firefox 38 (2015-05), which [removed `dom.indexedDB.warningQuota`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1123637):

From an answer by [mbrubeck](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/818987#answer-180011) at support.mozilla.com (I've replaced the links he provided with perma-versions):

> By default in Firefox 4, a site can use up to 50MB of IndexedDB storage. If it tries to use more than 50MB, Firefox will ask the user for permission: [http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/libpref/src/init/all.js#101](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/c3081b5db3d1db9213e5ed4531369f1970b0f60a/modules/libpref/src/init/all.js#l101)
>
> In Firefox for mobile devices (Google Android and Nokia Maemo), Firefox will ask for permission if a site tries to use more than 5MB: [http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/app/mobile.js#571](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/c3081b5db3d1db9213e5ed4531369f1970b0f60a/mobile/app/mobile.js#l571)
> [...]
>
> If the user grants permission for a site to exceed the 50 MB IndexedDB quota, then as far as I know Firefox does not impose any more limits. The only limits on the size of the IndexedDB database will be the user's disk space and operating system.
>
> The localStorage quota is 5000KB, and there is no way for a web site to ask the browser for permission to store more than that amount in localStorage.

Answer (score 40):

For a normal website using modern browsers, you don't need to worry about the available storage in indexedDB as it is way higher.

Maximum storage size depends on 2 things, **Browser** and **Disk space**.

So, Chrome and most of the chromium-based browsers allows 80% of the disk space to be used and from that 75% can be used by each origin. That means,
If you have a disk space of 100GB then 80GB can be used to store data in indexedDB and from that 60GB can be used by single origin.

Also, **Firefox** allows 2GB data to be stored by each origin and **Safari** allows 1GB per origin.

You can check the total space available and used space by-

```js
const quota = await navigator.storage.estimate();
const totalSpace = quota.quota;
const usedSpace = quota.usage;
```

Comment: Is there any estimate on the speed of look-ups when there are so many entries? Will there be any incurred latency waits to be anticipated ?

Comment: I think Chromium is also 2GB max per origin: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/storage/browser/quota/quota_settings.cc#68

Answer (score 36):

Adding to Nickolay answers, Here is the description of IndexedDB capacity in Chrome and IE

- **Chrome(Desktop)** : By default, For Web-apps chrome doesn't prompt the user while storing data using indexedDB API. It uses the concept of shared pool, here is the complete description - [Chrome HTML5 Offline Storage](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#types)
- **Chrome for Android** : Couldn't find any official link for stating quota. But from my experience, i have saved 300 MB of data without any prompts. Most probably same behavior as Desktop Chrome.
- **Internet Explorer 10** : By default , user is prompted for storage at 10 MB. 250 MB per domain is the hard limit by default, however user can configure their own limits till 1 GB.

Comment: How about IOS Safari? This could potentially be the most limiting of the browsers.

Comment: is indexdb storage different from the localstorage?

Comment: @tomexsans, see the discussion here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219953/how-is-localstorage-different-from-indexeddb