# How to undo navigator.storage.persist(() => {})

Tags: javascript, cacheapi

Is there a way to make cache storage box back to `best-effort` once is made `persistent` ?

Comment: Good question - unfortunately I'm not aware of a way and this article seems to agree (May 2020) https://web.dev/persistent-storage/#how-to-turn-off-persistent-storage
_"At this time, there is no programmatic way to tell the browser you no longer need persistent storage."_

Comment: Good question indeed - See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137095/clear-the-storage-persistent-flag-for-a-website, but this also only suggests to clear all browser data (for all websites).