# how to persist values when relaoad happens in input fields before submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

html:

```
<form name="shippingForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <p class="control-p col-sm-2" for="Address">Address Line1<b class="h4-color">*</b>:</p>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Address Line1" ng-model="shipping.addressLine1" class="input-width" ng-init ="shipping.addressLine1" required /><span class="custom-error" ng-show="shippingForm.Address.$dirty && shippingForm.Address.$error.required">Required.</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <p class="control-p col-sm-2" for="Address2">Address Line2:</p>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="AddressLine" placeholder="Address Line2" ng-model="shipping.addressLine2" class="input-width" />
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="pull-right btn div-margin-left" ng-disabled ="shippingForm.$invalid "ng-click="saveShipping(shipping)">CONTINUE</button>
</form>
```

js file:

```
$scope.saveShipping = function(shippingDetails){     
             var userData = storeLocally.get('userInfo');   
             var addr = "Shipping";

                if (userData.customerId){
                     addShippingInfo(shippingDetails,userData.customerId,addr);
                }
                else {        
                    storeLocally.set('shipInfo', shippingDetails);
                    //$location.path(path);
                }
         };         

         function addShippingInfo(shipAdd, custId, addr){

             appServices.addAddress(shipAdd, custId, addr).then(function (d){
                if (d){
                        storeLocally.set('shipInfo', shippingDetails);
                        //console.log("inside function", shippingDetails);
                        //$location.path(path);
                    }           
                 },
                  function (d) {
                      if (d.status == 500) {
                          window.alert("Oops! some problem here..");
                      };
                 });
         };
```

I want to persist the values in fields even after reloading page before submission. I tried cookies but seems like its not good option to use this.
Please provide me some of your suggestions to fix this thing.

Comment: Save the values to back end and when loading begins in front end, get the values back from back end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localStorage`, which does not use cookies, and jQuery's `.change()` so that everytime a form item changes, use localStorage to store its new value, and on page load, get those values, if they exist.

Sample HTML

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
```

Javascript

```
if(localStorage.getItem("name") != null)
    {
    $('#name').val() = localStorage.getItem("name");
    }

$('#name').change(function()
    {
    localStorage.setItem("name", $('#name').val());
    });
```

Then, upon submitting the form, you'll want to reset any `localStorage` variables you used back to null.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't believe that localStorage is cleared when the browser is closed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537112/when-is-localstorage-cleared

Comment: My bad, accidently crossed it with sessionStorage in my head. Updating my post.

Comment: Thanks @JakeWood for answering.  I will try to do it myself using sessionStorage.