# On reload of the application, localStorage data will clear or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I want to use some data in my entire application. I am using localStorage to store the data .I am using it in my application but here is my issue , on Reload my entire localStorage values are removed from browser. Can anyone please tell me,  localStoage values are removed when user reloads the application? If yes suggest me any other solution to use the data in entire application.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: That should not be the case. localStorage data will persist as long as the use does not explicitly clears, unless you programatically clear it in the conosle, or in your app JS (e.g. [`window.localStorage.clear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is localStorage cleared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537112/when-is-localstorage-cleared)

Answer (score 3):

Localstorage is stored in the system, reload application would not erase it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two variables localStorage and sessionStorage .

The difference between two is that data in localStorage has no expiration while sessionStorage clears your data when the page session ends.It depends whatever variable you want to use as per your requirement.

So localStorage will not clear your data when your page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `window.localStorage.clear()` in your file and see if it is getting called on reload, as thats the only way to clear our localStorage and you might be hitting on it accidentally.

> The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across browser sessions. localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except that while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed.

so Ideally it should not clear the values of localStorage unlee you have manually triggered something to clear that (check for any method which is clearing it and triggered on page reload) if all looks good then there are next cases like exceptions:

> **Exceptions**
>
> *SecurityError*
>
> The request violates a policy decision, or the origin is not a valid scheme/host/port tuple (this can happen if the origin uses the file: or data: scheme, for example). For example, the user may have their browser configured to deny permission to persist data for the specified origin.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cookies for store data until the session clears. That way your data will not be cleared when the app reload every time.

**Use below code to store data in cookies**,

```
document.cookie = "sampleData=www.samplesite.com";
document.cookie = "sampleUser=user001";
```

**use below code to retrieve data from cookies**,

```
function getCookieData(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
      if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
  }

  function getSampleSite() {
    var _st = getCookieData("sampleData");
    return (_st != null) ? _st : "";
  }

  function getUser() {
    var _st = getCookieData("sampleUser");
    return (_st != null) ? _st : "";
  }
```