# JQuery preserve data on element remove from dom

Tags: jquery

I have some data on the div elements, which I then remove from dom at some point (and push to array) and reinsert later int to the dom, but the data gets lost. Is there a way to preserve this data for later when I reinsert it into the dom. Its not just one or two data-attributes I could create in html, but little more than that.

I am removing elements from dom the following way:

```
arr = [];

playlistContent.find('.box').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this));
})
playlistContent.empty();//remove also some other elements present in there
```

Comment: How are you removing it from the DOM?  There is a difference between `remove()` and `detach()`  https://api.jquery.com/detach

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: `empty()` is going to essentially do a `remove()` on all the children of the element.  If you want the data to be preserved, you are going to have to detach the elements you want to preserve, not remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detach the elements you want to later readd.  I left the empty in there in case there were other elements in the content other than the boxes.

```
var arr = playlistContent.find('.box').detach().get();

playlistContent.empty();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use localStorage, which will survive even a page refresh:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

See Also:

[When is localStorage cleared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537112/when-is-localstorage-cleared/37105645#37105645)