# When does browser session storage gets expired?

Tags: javascript, browser, session-storage

Currently, I am storing a few things in local storage like the last visited page. I need them even when the user logs off and logs in again. I was planning to move them into Session storage and thus I wanted to know the validity of items in Session Storage of browser.

Comment: Read this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp). 
If you want to keep the data even after the browser windows is closed, try using cookies

Comment: `sessionStorage` doesn't really expire (for a particular window/tab), but data is persisted until the user explicitly clears it. [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8537188/9172668) a good answer that quickly highlights it. You can set up a [timeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) then clear the storage with `sessionStorage.clear()`

Answer (score 1):

The items in session storage are only available in a page's session.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

> - A page session lasts as long as the browser is open, and survives over
>     page reloads and restores.
> - Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the
>     value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how
>     session cookies work.
> - Opening multiple tabs/windows with the same URL creates sessionStorage
>     for each tab/window.
> - Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears
>     objects in sessionStorage.