# When is localStorage cleared or data get deleted/removed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage, shopping-cart

I am working on implementing a shopping cart feature for online shopping web app using Spring Boot. I have used localStorage to store user's cart item inside it. But the thing is, suppose I have stored some items in the cart and closed my app and browser too and next day I opened that app again to see my cart item. But I did not find any item stored inside cart. So, is there any automatic removal of data when stored in browser using localStorage?

As, currently showing me zero items in cart. Is there like, when we exit or close the app or browser tab then data get removed automatically? **Please suggest me good answers as I need to make my cart feature accurate. If need to share code then please let me know.**

Below is my script to add items into cart:

```
function addtocart(productid, productname) {
            var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
            var productimage = document.getElementById("pimage").src; 
            var quantity = $("#quantity").val() != "" ? parseInt($("#quantity").val()) : 0;
            var price = $("#pprice").text();
            var pprice = price.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
            var cart = localStorage.getItem("cart");
            var pcart = JSON.parse(cart) != null ? JSON.parse(cart) : [];
            var list = pcart;
            var present_or_not = pcart.findIndex(item => item.productid == productid);
            if (cart == null || present_or_not == null || present_or_not == -1) {
                    var product = {
                      productid: productid,
                      productname: productname,
                      pprice: pprice,
                      quantity: quantity,
                      productimage : productimage,
                      category : category,
                };
                pcart.push(product);
                localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(pcart));
                swal({title: "Item Added", text: "Item added to cart", type: "success"},
                        function(){
                    location.reload();
                   })
              } else {
                var actual_stored_product = pcart[present_or_not];
                pcart.splice(present_or_not, 1);  
                var actual_qty = actual_stored_product.quantity == null || actual_stored_product.quantity == "" ? 0 : actual_stored_product.quantity;
                var actual_price = actual_stored_product.pprice == null || actual_stored_product.pprice == "" ? 0 : actual_stored_product.pprice;
                actual_stored_product.quantity = parseInt(actual_qty) + quantity ;
                actual_stored_product.pprice = parseFloat(actual_price)+parseFloat(pprice);
                pcart.push(actual_stored_product);
                localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(pcart));
                swal({title: "Item Quantity Increased", text: "Item Quantity Updated of: "+productid, type: "success"},
                        function(){
                    location.reload();
                   })
              }
        }
```

Comment: It clears when you close the browser.

Comment: @ObsidianAge i think she is using localStorage not sessionStorage.

Comment: Okay, it means that I need to store cart items using sessionStorage?

Comment: `localStorage` data is domain specific. Example localStorage for `abc.com` will be different from `xyz.com` and `localStorage` data get cleared if the tab is open in incognito mode or private, else `localStorage` have no expiration date

Comment: Okay then what is the best way to store cart items so that user would be able to see after 10 days or one months too, if required?

Comment: @brk "localStorage data get cleared if the tab is open in incognito mode or private," not really, it's more that from these modes the browser will treat that origin as opaque, and thus you won't have access to the previously stored data. But it won't clear what was saved, e.g you can very well save from a "normal" session, go to incognito, come back with a "normal" session and retrieve the data saved in first step.

Comment: LocalStorage is probably the best way for small data. Show what you have so we can see why it's not working.

Comment: Okay I am updating my question with some code that I have implemented.

Comment: @Kaiido well according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage it get `cleared`. May be it is a too generalised term

Comment: @brk, Yes, but only the Storage area from the private tabs session. The one from the "normal" session is not cleared.

Comment: ... can't find anything obviously wrong in this code. A few useless checks (like `present_or_not == null`) but nothing that should affect what you experience. Do you have any browser extension active (particularly privacy ones), or are you using a privacy oriented browser (like Tor or Brave)?

Comment: No. I do not have any bowser extension or anything else.

Comment: I am using chrome browser.

Comment: Current answer did not solved my issue, I marked it by mistake. :-P

Comment: From `chrome://settings/cookies` What do you have for "Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows"?

Comment: Let me check first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235368/discussion-between-rakhi-sharma-and-kaiido).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is localStorage cleared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537112/when-is-localstorage-cleared)

Answer (score 1):

**LocalStorage** will not delete the data even if you close the browser and reopen

**SessionStorage** will clear out the data once the tab is closed

But its specific to browser. if you are running the project in different browser the data will not be present there

Refer this sandbox for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/n77o30n824

Comment: I think another very important difference is session storage is not shared between tabs.  It is much like tab scoped state while local storage is shared between tabs.  (ie. you can throw a tabId into session storage and store all your tab data in localstorage so a user can pick up where he left off and server side you can show him things he was in flight - like if he was booking a ticket but accidentally closed that tab).