# Store binary files locally in Google Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, file-io, safari

I am developing an HTML5-Application and I want to store some binary files locally to view them in offline mode. I found a way to do it on mobile devices with phonegap. Now I want to store those files using some kind of plugin in Google Chrome or Safari. I found the [Gears API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/gears/) but the storage of files is deprectated. Does anyone know a way to store binary files locally using Google Chrome or Safari?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gears API has been deprecated in favor of [AppCache](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html) found in [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html).

Comment: The problem is, that I want to store pdf files dynamically depending on some situations. The AppCache is for static resources as far as i know.

Comment: I believe you can use [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) in that case (see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692820/max-size-in-indexeddb) for details on size limits.)

Comment: Thank you for that. Do you know another way which doesn't have these limitations (maybe a plugin) ?!?

Comment: I would not treat asking a user if they agree to increase the limits as a "limitation" :) Anyway, safety is important, and you would not want any plugin out there to be able to fill up your hard drive with a huge something, would you? You could also look into Local Storage for Flash, but it looks like they also have certain limits (see [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I think HTML5 filesystem api ist the best solution for your case. No size limitations so far as i know.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: According to http://www.chromestatus.com/features Safari and Firefox are opposed to implementing this API but there's no explanation why.