# IndexedDB & localStorage Storage Limits

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

From what I can understand Chrome imposes a "soft" limit of 5Mb on the size of data stored in localStorage and IndexedDB.  There are a number of things here that are not clear to me

- What precisely is meant by "soft" in this context?
- Does this mean localStorage:5Mb + IndexedDB:5Mb?
- I have not hit the buffers yet but then I keep clearing out my browser stores as I develop my app.  What happens when the limits are reached?  An exception is thrown and needs to be caught?
- Would there be much mileage in compressing data prior to storage?  [This](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) seems to offer an excellent route if data compression is worth doing.

Compression would come at the cost of loosing the benefits of being able seamlessly to store/fetch JSON in IndexedDB (though this can be made transparent to my app with little extra effort).

I'd much appreciate any guidelines with these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up a fiddle to examine what happens when the soft storage limits are breached - and also to test the utility of compressing what gets stored.  Here is the fiddle

[Local Storage Test](http://jsfiddle.net/KRxqf/2/)

I have used the compression routines [here](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) for the test.  The actual compression is easily done

```
var compr = LZString.compress(uncompr);
```

**Notes**

1. The test need some time to execute so be patient!
2. To increase the size of the stored data just increase maxTimes
3. Compression works - very well indeed.  However, as the tests will demonstrate, it can only realistically be used when storing relatively small (order of a few kb at the most) strings.  For longer strings the compression itself takes too long and is liable to make your app unresponsive.  I suspect that it would be better to question the need to store excessively long strings than to compress them.
4. I use this technique for storing locally displayed HTML documents in localStorage and to store a range of configuration data objects in an IndexedDB database.
5. Compressing data stored in IndexedDB means you loose the seamless storage/retrieval of JS objects that it offers.  However, this can be dealt with easily via a simple wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the listed answers of your doubts:

- Google Chrome has the quota of 5 MB. Here is the link to the specification - http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#property-local-QUOTA_BYTES. Soft limit means it is the default quota, you can ask the user for his permission for more disk-space.
- Quotas for localStorage are different from IndexedDB - here is the link for disk-space quota  for IndexedDB - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20675480/867629
- When the localStorage reaches 5MB Google Chrome produces an error in the javascript console log:

  ```
  Uncaught Error: QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: DOM Exception 22
  ```

I haven't tried compression with locallStorage, so no idea about that.

Comment: Thanks. I assume one can trap this error in a normal JavaScript try..catch construct?