# How many objects (columns) can exist using IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I need to work in a indexedDB database for an hybrid application (intel XDK), it works fine with 50 columns but now I must to work with 254 columns, is this possible or there is something that I must to know before develop this?

Thank you all.

Comment: I dont imagine there is a limit to the "shape" of your DB, just the amount of "space" it takes up: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7867985/648350 however, are you 100% sure you need 254 columns? (perhaps there's a better way to structure your data?)

Comment: Thanks haxxxton, and yes, its possible to restructure the design to reduce the amount of the number of the columns but now I'm against the clock and want to use a previous design (the one with 50 columns) that can help to reduce the time a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are no columns in indexedDB.

Comment: The limit is based on the overall size of the data, and whether you are using limited storage. If using limited storage, then you are typically limited to something like 5 MB of data. If unlimited, then you are limited I think primarily by available disk space. To find the maximum number of objects you can store, figure out the type of storage, estimate the average byte size of your objects, and divide.