# storing data in the chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, store

Please tell me what is normally a data store, large data in Google's extension. I know there is a chrome.storage - now I keep everything in it - a couple of keys. But to make a selection, etc. not convenient from the word at all, there is a possibility that the data will be lost, etc.

I know there is WebSql and indexedDb, but they are declared deprecated. Can eat still variants? excluding a separate server that will store all the data in the mysql database.

Comment: Possibility that the data will be lost?

Comment: @PredatorIWD for example, an incorrect entry

Comment: IndexedDB is not deprecated. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

For small amounts of data you have "[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage)" which is usually 5 Mb, and you have "[chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)" which has 5 Mb locally and a part of it can be uploaded to Google servers (for cross-browser sharing) - on the server you have just 100 Kb.

Then there's IndexedDB, which seems to vary from 10 Mb up to 300 Mb and maybe even a bit more. See [Maximum item size in IndexedDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692820/maximum-item-size-in-indexeddb)
and [this document](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#managing_quota) which describes quotas on IndexedDB.

If you want to treat a lot of data, you have to either upload it to your (or a 3rd-party-provided) server-side database, or create a normal desktop app (if you want it locally).

Comment: @wOxxOm that's what I've said - you can only upload 100 Kb.
If you put 5 Mb into localStorage, can you still put 5 Mb into chrome.storage ? Is it 10 Mb total?

Answer (score 0):

There is comparing about localstorage with chrome storage. You can easly decide which is better.

[window.localStorage vs chrome.storage.local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279495/window-localstorage-vs-chrome-storage-local)