# Storing a large amount of data in the browser

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm working on a web application for searching, filtering, and exploring a fixed data set. The data set fits in about 10 MB of JSON. It will change a few times a year, and it can be updated incrementally.

I would like to store this data in the browser to avoid latency. This is a hard requirement -- the profound gain in responsiveness is the entire reason to create this application when many excellent alternatives exist. I accept that it won't work well for some users.

What is the best way to store this data persistently in the browser? I could pack it into localStorage, but I'd have to decompress and `JSON.parse` it on every page load. I've heard good things about IndexedDB, but I'm not sure that it's well-suited to storing a single giant blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If your data is smaller than 10MB then you could store it in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values) however the size of the storage can customised by the user so this seems on the limit. Also you would be stuck doing parse/stringify frequently, and only able to filter in-memory.

Using indexedDB is probably your best option as [it can storage more](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/). There is [apparently no limit to the size of a single item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692820/maximum-item-size-in-indexeddb), so you could do one giant value blob if you wanted to.

Can you describe the structure of the data further? If its a list then your data is partitionable. You could leverage indexes to enable searching for exact list item values quite efficiently.

Comment: The application is a Magic: The Gathering card directory, and the data is lists of cards, sets, printings, and other related information. I would like to do the filtering and other processing in memory anyway; it's a lot easier, it's probably faster, and it isn't *that* much data (fewer than 20,000 cards). Queries will often be much more complex than a simple index match.