# Load a large .obj file to WASM OpenGL

Tags: c++, webgl, webassembly, emscripten

I am loading .obj models using the `preload` EMSCRIPTEN flag so that I am able to use them in WASM/WebGL from C++/OpenGL ES, the memory consumption goes over the limit when loading a 64mb .obj, I am able to load smaller models but from that size onward I crash. What is the correct way of loading large files so that I can access them in C++? I also tried the `embed` command but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

For a large file, place it in the server as a static resource and use [the Fetch API](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/fetch.html#persisting-data). You can let the browser cache it by using the `EMSCRIPTEN_FETCH_PERSIST_FILE` flag. It uses the HTML5 IndexedDB designed to store large data, such as 1GB. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692820/maximum-item-size-in-indexeddb) for the size limit.